# Getting a full month report after searching a date in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, ef-core-6.0

I need to generate a full month report base on some criteria. The first condition is- I am taking a anonyms **Date**  from user and after checking all the condition it will generate full month report.

I tried to generate the report but this is returning a day wise report. Everything is fine except the month. Please help me to do this.

```
[HttpGet("inner-join/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public IActionResult GetReport(DateTime id)
{
  try
  {
    IEnumerable<BTBPending> objBTBPendingList = _unitOfWork.BTBPending.GetAll(includeProperties: "ProformaInvoice,ContractList,SupplierList,CountryList,ItemList,BuyerList,StyleList,TradeTermList,ErpRemarksList,StatusList,LcNoList,UdAmendList");

    IEnumerable<ProformaInvoice> objProformaInvoiceList = _unitOfWork.ProformaInvoice.GetAll(includeProperties: "ActualContract,ContractList,SupplierList,CountryList,ItemList,BuyerList,StyleList,TradeTermList");


    var query = objBTBPendingList
        .Where(x => x.LcOpenDate == id)
        .Where(x => x.CountryListId == 26)
        .Where(x => x.StatusListId == 12 || x.StatusListId == 13 || x.StatusListId == 14)
        .Join(objProformaInvoiceList,
              btbPending => btbPending.ContractListId,
              pi => pi.ContractListId, 
              (btbPending, pi) => new
              {
                LcNo = btbPending.LcNoList,
                Value = btbPending.PiValue,

                ContractNo = pi.ContractList,
                Buyer = pi.BuyerList,
                PiNo = pi.PINo,
                Supplier = pi.SupplierList,
                Item = pi.ItemList
              }).ToList();


     return Ok(query);
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
     return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error, Please Try Again Leter!");
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot that here I stored all the date in LcOpenDate Column. And  I need to generate the Monthly report of total Lc Open in a Month. For Example : If a user enter 2022-01-31 then the report should be full month report of January 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make condition for the month, you are doing on the date. so do like this.

```
.Where(x => x.LcOpenDate.Month == id.Month && x.LcOpenDate.Year == id.Year)
```

Here I am assuming both `id` and `LcOpenDate` are from the same timezones.

As per the comment, `LcOpenDate` is `DateTime?`, so you need to do this.

`LcOpenDate.Value.Month` and `LcOpenDate.Value.Year`

Comment: Its shows the following error-  " `DateTime?` doesn't contains a definition for `Month`, and  no accessible extension method `Month` accepting a first argument of type `DateTime?` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). "

Comment: try `LcOpenDate.Value.Month` and `LcOpenDate.Value.Year`

Comment: Its working properly but in the database in `LcOpenDate` column I stored full date like `2022-01-31` and the URL is like `https://localhost:44332/btb-pending-report/inner-join/2022-01-31` that means user searching the full date and my system will generate the `month wise` report

Comment: @MasumRayhan what is the problem with this?

Comment: @MasumRayhan another option is that you have to pass only the month and year in the URL. and take them as a single string parameter (2022-01) then split it by - . Or paas month and year in two parameters. But it's very simple now, you should do this by yourself. StackOverflow is not to provide a readymade code. and this will be a separate question. you can ask a new question.

Comment: The problem is that when I hit the URL its just shows the relevant date information. not full month wise report.

Comment: @MasumRayhan can you provide the screenshots of request , response, expected response

Comment: try `LcOpenDate.Value.Month` and `LcOpenDate.Value.Year` this method is working perfectly. Thanks a lot @vivek nuna

Comment: I need another help. I need to calculate `totalValue` from this `Value = btbPending.PiValue` column which I got after joining the tables. How can I do that? I already tried to use `Sum` method but its shows error

Comment: @MasumRayhan what is the error?

Comment: I tried this `totalValue = btbPending.PiValue.Sum(t => t.PiValue)` and its shows the following error - `decimal?` does not contain a definition for `sum` and no accessible extension method `sum` accepting a first argument of type `decimal?` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).`

Comment: After joining the table,actually I need to calculate `totalvalue` from this `Value = btbPending.PiValue` column

Comment: you have `using System.Linq;` on top of your class?

Comment: Yes, I used this.

Comment: anyways this is a separate question, Can you ask a new question and share the link with me, I will have a look @MasumRayhan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74422448/sum-columns-from-joined-tables-to-get-a-calculated-value-using-linq?noredirect=1#comment131382599_74422448

Comment: @MasumRayhan are you there? I have added a comment to your question, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. Its worked. @vivek nuna I have sent you a connection request on LinkedIn.

Comment: I have added as an answer on your question

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` gives your a full date and time and looks something like

```
2022-11-11 11:44:53 PM
```

What is likely going on is that when you are storing the data in the database, you are ommitting the time. Something like this:

```
var date = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day) 
// 2022-11-11 12:00:00 AM
```

This is the only way `x.LcOpenDate == id` would work. Otherwise it would only return items with the open date at the exact time you provided up to the millisecond.
Try this instead:

```
.Where(x => x.LcOpenDate.Year == id.Year &&  x.LcOpenDate.Month == id.Month)
```

Additionally, if you are on .net 6+ you can use [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) and [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0)

Comment: as vivek mentioned, use `id.Value.Month`

Comment: This shows me the following error - Operator `Year` cannot be applied to operands of type `DateTime` and `int`

Comment: are you sure you have double equals `==` and not single `=` ?

Comment: `.Where(x => x.LcOpenDate.Value.Year == id.Year &&  x.LcOpenDate.Value.Month == id.Month)`

Comment: Yes I use double equals `==`

Comment: what's the CS code for the error?