# Sum Columns from joined tables to get a calculated value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-6.0

In the below context, I have joined two tables based on some criteria. Now I need to `calculate total value` from the result of that `joined table`.

```
[HttpGet("inner-join/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public IActionResult GetReport(DateTime id)
{
  try
  {
    IEnumerable<BTBPending> objBTBPendingList = _unitOfWork.BTBPending.GetAll(includeProperties: "ProformaInvoice,ContractList,SupplierList,CountryList,ItemList,BuyerList,StyleList,TradeTermList,ErpRemarksList,StatusList,LcNoList,UdAmendList");

    IEnumerable<ProformaInvoice> objProformaInvoiceList = _unitOfWork.ProformaInvoice.GetAll(includeProperties: "ActualContract,ContractList,SupplierList,CountryList,ItemList,BuyerList,StyleList,TradeTermList");


    var query = objBTBPendingList
        .Where(x => x.LcOpenDate.Value.Year == id.Year && x.LcOpenDate.Value.Month == id.Month)
        .Where(x => x.CountryListId == 26)
        .Where(x => x.StatusListId == 12 || x.StatusListId == 13 || x.StatusListId == 14)
        .Join(objProformaInvoiceList,
              btbPending => btbPending.ContractListId,
              pi => pi.ContractListId, 
              (btbPending, pi) => new
              {
                LcNo = btbPending.LcNoList,
                Value = btbPending.PiValue,

                ContractNo = pi.ContractList,
                Buyer = pi.BuyerList,
                PiNo = pi.PINo,
                Supplier = pi.SupplierList,
                Item = pi.ItemList
              }).ToList();


     return Ok(query);
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
     return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error, Please Try Again Leter!");
   }
}
```

After joining the these two table I need to return the `sum`  from the below `Value = btbPending.PiValue` Column which I got `after joining` the tables.

```
.Join(objProformaInvoiceList,
      btbPending => btbPending.ContractListId,
      pi => pi.ContractListId, 
      (btbPending, pi) => new
      {
      LcNo = btbPending.LcNoList,
      Value = btbPending.PiValue,

      ContractNo = pi.ContractList,
      Buyer = pi.BuyerList,
      PiNo = pi.PINo,
      Supplier = pi.SupplierList,
      Item = pi.ItemList
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why you can't use [`sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: when I used `Sum` , its shows the following error - `decimal?` does not contain a definition for `sum` and no accessible extension method `sum` accepting a first argument of type `decimal?`  could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).`

Comment: have you tried this after you query `var sum = query.Select(c=>c.Value).Sum();`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the sum like this `var sum = query.Select(c => c.Value).Sum();`